# Print cusrom strings between output lines of Get-Child items in Powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, get-childitem

need your little help here. I am trying to print custom string in between output of Get-ChildItem cmdlet in Powershell but I am not sure how to get that done.

For example, I am trying to find all files which has keyword "PostTestScript" in them and I am doing below.

```
Get-ChildItem | Select-String -Pattern "PostTestScript"
```

And this is the output its generating

```
aaa1.txt:31:    PostTestScript     = ''
aaa2.txt:31:    PostTestScript     = ''
aaa3.txt:31:    PostTestScript     = ''
```

Now what should I do if I want to print custom output(doted line) in between filenames like below ?

```
aaa1.txt:31:    PostTestScript     = ''
-------------------------------------------
aaa2.txt:31:    PostTestScript     = ''
-------------------------------------------
aaa3.txt:31:    PostTestScript     = '' 
-------------------------------------------
```

Comment: `Get-ChildItem | Select-String -Pattern "PostTestScript" | ForEach-Object {$_;'-'*50}`

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for. Is there a way to customize this ? For example, if I want to print this dotted line after every 2 lines or after every 5 lines etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Line separator after each output line

```
$pattern = "PostTestScript"
Get-ChildItem | Select-String -Pattern $pattern | 
    ForEach-Object {
        $_
        '-'*50       
    }
```

Line separator on filename change

```
$pattern = "PostTestScript"
$lastFile = [string]::Empty
Get-ChildItem | Select-String -Pattern $pattern | 
    ForEach-Object {
        if (($lastFile -ne [string]::Empty) -and ($_.FileName -ne $lastFile)) {
            '-'*50       
        }
        $lastFile = $_.FileName
        $_
    }
'='*50                   ### line separator at utter end (optional)
```

Line separator after each `$everyN` output lines

```
$pattern = "PostTestScript"
$everyN = 4
$i = 0
Get-ChildItem | Select-String -Pattern $pattern | 
    ForEach-Object {
        if (($i -ne 0) -and ($i % $everyN) -eq 0) {
            '-'*50
        }
        $i++
        $lastFile = $_.FileName
        $_
    }
'='*50                   ### line separator at utter end (optional)
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for.